# How to copy text from a pdf?

Tags: pdf

I have tried Foxit/Adobe/PDF Reader to try selecting a text section in a pdf but have failed so far. Adobe explicitly lists this functionality @ http://blogs.adobe.com/readermobile/2013/06/03/adobe-reader-10-1-now-available-for-windows-phone-8/ and it works on a few pdfs I have but not on all.

Also the pdf is definitely not scanned bitmapped images since I am able to select text on my laptop in the very same pdf.